# How to add elements to json array from Java interface at run time

Tags: java, json, append

I want to add the elements to JSON array from the Java GUI at runtime

but every time the new array is created in JSON file

Java GUI to enter data:

```
String _itemType = txtItemType.getText();
int _itemQuantity = Integer.parseInt(txtItemQuantity.getText());
JSONWriteExample obj = new JSONWriteExample(_itemType, _itemQuantity);
obj.jsonParse();
```

JSON:

```
public JSONWriteExample(String type, int number) {
    this.type = type;
    this.quantity = number;  
}

public void jsonParse() throws IOException {
    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(); 
    Map m = new LinkedHashMap(4); 
    JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(); 

    m = new LinkedHashMap(2); 
    m.put("Item Type", type); 
    m.put("Quantity", quantity);       
    ja.add(m); 
    jo.put("Items", ja); 
    FileWriter file=new FileWriter("jsonArray.json",true);
    file.append(jo.toString());
    file.flush(); 
    file.close(); 
}
```

I expect the output like:

```
{  
   "Items":[  
      {  
         "Item Type":"TV",
         "Quantity":3
      },
      {  
         "Item Type":"phone",
         "Quantity":3
      }
   ]
}
```

But new array is created each time like:

```
{  
   "Items":[  
      {  
         "Item Type":"TV",
         "Quantity":3
      }
   ]
}{  
   "Items":[  
      {  
         "Item Type":"phone",
         "Quantity":3
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: You ***do*** just append the json object to the end of the text file. You'd need to read the content of the file, modify it and overwrite the whole file, if you want to fix this (unless you want to determine how to overwrite parts at the end of the file to achieve this result, which is more complex and harder to maintain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @fabian mentioned in the comment - you should first parse the file content, modify and overwrite the file. Here is a sample code how to achieve that:

First of all, I don't know what json library you're using, but I would strongly suggest to use the following:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.8</version>
</dependency>
```

It will generally ease your work with json. If you don't want to use libraries you can still follow the instruction, but adapt it for your needs. The whole implementation is like this:

```
public class JSONWriteExample {
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "jsonArray.json";
    private static final Path FILE_PATH = Paths.get(FILE_NAME);
    private final String type;
    private final int quantity;

    public JSONWriteExample(String type, int quantity) {
        this.type = type;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public void jsonParse() throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        if (Files.notExists(FILE_PATH)) {
            Files.createFile(FILE_PATH);
            objectMapper.writeValue(FILE_PATH.toFile(), createItems(new ArrayList<>()));
        }
        Items items = objectMapper.readValue(FILE_PATH.toFile(), Items.class);
        final List<Item> itemsList = items.getItems();
        objectMapper.writeValue(FILE_PATH.toFile(), createItems(itemsList));
    }

    private Items createItems(List<Item> itemsList) {
        final Item item = new Item();
        item.setType(type);
        item.setQuantity(quantity);
        itemsList.add(item);
        final Items items = new Items();
        items.setItems(itemsList);
        return items;
    }

    public static class Items {
        private List<Item> items;
        // Setters, Getters
    }

    public static class Item {
        private String type;
        private int quantity;
        // Setters, Getters
    }
 }
```

Okay, what's going on in this code?

1. First of all, note the usage of Java 7 NIO - recommended way to work with files in java.
2. In `jsonParse` method we first check if file exists.

   - If it does - then we read it to the data class (`Items`) that describes our model. The reading part is done under the hood of this library, just the fileds of your json file should have the same names as the fields of the data classes (or specified with `JsonAlias` annotation.
   - If it doesn't - then we create it first and populate with the initial values.
3. `ObjectMapper` is the class from the library and it's used to read\write json files.

Now if we run this piece of code, e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    JSONWriteExample example = new JSONWriteExample("TV", 3);
    example.jsonParse();

    JSONWriteExample example2 = new JSONWriteExample("phone", 3);
    example2.jsonParse();
}
```

json file will look like:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "TV",
      "quantity": 3
    },
    {
      "type": "TV",
      "quantity": 3
    },
    {
      "type": "phone",
      "quantity": 3
    }
  ]
}
```